# using forEch to render react components

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use forEach to render my components.

```
{myArray.forEach((value, index) => {
    <MyComponent {...value} />
})}
```

this is not doing anything. but if I do

```
{myArray.forEach((value, index) => {
    console.log(index, value)
})}

//also tried with...

{myArray.forEach((index) => {
    <MyComponent {...myArray[index]} />;
})}
```

I see the element in the console. why is that? I read that forEach returns *undefined* and I should use `map` to iterate but why it shows the object in the console but doesn't render my component? thank you

Comment: Well you answered yourself, simply use map instead of forEach, map returns a new array, forEach does not return anything.

Comment: it's more like to understand why is that happening. i know I can use map.

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Answer (score 0):

Foreach doesn't return anything. But for rendering any component inside the `jsx` you have to return an array of `JSX.Elements` or `HTMLElements`. Try using `map` instead of `forEach`.

```
{array.map((value, index) => {
    return <MyComponent {...value} />
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing forEach function does not return a value but rather only executing the code that is inside of it, therefor you see the console.logs.

In React it is best practice to use the **`map`** function.

So instead of doing this

```
{array.forEach((value, index) => {
    <MyComponent {...value} />
})}
```

Do this

```
{array.map((value, index) => {
    return <MyComponent {...value} />
})}
```

Comment: yes it executes code thats inside it (like console.log) why it can't execute the component code? that's the part i don't understand. and if it doesn't return anything what could be a good use of forEach?